# Show in explorer is not opening in android studio 3.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I am facing issues with opening the file location in explorer.

If I try to view a specific file in the Windows File Explorer via `Right click -> Show in Explorer`, nothing happens.

It used to work in older versions 3.0.1, however unable to do the same in 3.1.0

[image]

Comment: Just checked it in AS 3.0.1 with the Android and Project view, it works fine. Don't have 3.1.0 to check it though...

Comment: Yes it's working fine in 3.0.1 but not in 3.1.0 @ahasbini

Comment: Odd, I'm on 3.1.0 and this works for me. Problem must be on your end.

Comment: @Morgan I have tried different types like Restart AS ,clean  and rebuilt the project but still same problem

Comment: Where is your project located? All my projects are in the default folder `AndroidStudioProjects`

Comment: My project file location is  E:\ANDROID_STUDIO\App @Morgan

Comment: Try changing the view from Android to Project. If that doesn't work, try creating a new project, this time in the default folder, see if that works.

Comment: I tried changing views and also created a new project but no success so far

Comment: How about create a new project in different partition of harddisk/ssd maybe?

Comment: also facing same issue.

Comment: I'm also updating my Android Studio from version 3.0.1 to 3.1.0 but **Show in Explorer works fine for me**.

Comment: I too facing same issue, and also can't explore the debug apk.

Comment: It is busted it appears. Not working on Win 8.1 at least.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue in AS 3.1.2

Comment: It stopped from one day to the other in version 3.1.3 now, too.

Comment: @Thommy do you have any solution for this?

Comment: @vikassingh which solution is working for above question? actually your accepted answer was not working.

Comment: @Arbaz.in You need to do same as An08NY said...I have done same as he has told as it's working fine for me...

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: @vikassingh thanks for asking the question it help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered by Thommy, you need to setup your path variables accordingly.

Just try adding the below paths to your environment variables and then I think it should work fine.

Add:

1 - `C:\Windows`

2 - `%SystemRoot%`

3 - `%SystemRoot%\system32`

[image: Path Variables Screenshot]

Comment: thanks, brother after a long time, now it's working as I expected.

Comment: post your path variables

Comment: @Arbaz.in add these in your path variables, it should work.

Comment: So its like this **C:\Windows\%SystemRoot%SystemRoot%\system32**?

Comment: edit your path variable, then add them all separately after a semicolin

Comment: but i have a windows 8.1 and it allow through single line

Comment: try copying this: C:\\Windows\;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32;

Answer (score 4):

In the Logs Android Studio stated that `explorer` command could not be found, so
I solved it by adding `C:\Windows\explorer.exe` to my Path Variable and restarted Android Studio. 
 
I don't think it is (only) an Android Studio Bug because `explorer` command wasn't working in `cmd` either. 
Also it is strange since it worked in 3.2 beta while 3.1.3 wasn't working.

Comment: Did you try restarting?

Comment: @Thommy i tried above solution but its not working and also restarting my system after setting path.

Comment: @Arbaz.in Click on "Open in Explorer" in Android Studio and then check the logs, if it says "command explorer not found". If that is not the case, my solution will not work.

Comment: @Thommy i tried **(Show in Explorer)**  same and i didn't get any log in Logcat.

Comment: @Arbaz.in Not Logcat, the logfile in Android Studio's config directory: {user}\.AndroidStudio3.1\system\log

Comment: @Thommy i navigate to that folder but i cant found like that. what was issue with Android Studio actually i am also not able to open apk file from android studio when i tried to build apk

Comment: @Thommy its not working for me but thanks for the response on my comment.

Comment: @Arbaz.in The way you describe it your problem is a completly different one than what is asked in this question. Please open a new one.

Comment: @Thommy  ,actually my issue was resolved with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51166662/5995648)

Comment: Well that is the same as mine